# Hive table column date format

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to create a table with a field of type `date`. I store only the year field. So I am trying to format it as `YYYY`. But hive is not taking the format command. My statement is as below...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS la1 (vendor varchar(20), 
country varchar(25), name1 varchar(256), city varchar(40), 
district varchar(40), pobox varchar(40), poboxpostelcode varchar(20), createdon date format 'YYYY')
```

`timestamp` field type also not working

Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`format` is not supported.
Only ISO formats are supported.

- Date:      `yyyy-MM-dd`
- Timestamp: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

If you want to hold only the `yyyy` part use character/integer types.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. In that case, I will declare the field as `int`.